# IntelliJ IDEA Linux Mint Problems

Tags: intellij-idea, linux-mint

When I run IntelliJ on Linux Mint, I get an warning on the terminal screen.

```
 /IDEA/idea-IU-141.178.9/bin $ ./idea.sh 
[  47358]   WARN - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
[  63287]   WARN - .ExternalResourceManagerExImpl - Cannot find standard resource. filename:/META-INF/tapestry_5_3.xsd class=class com.intellij.javaee.ResourceRegistrarImpl, classLoader:null
```

I'm using Java 8 64-bit.  I thing that this error is leading to some CSS loading problem.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a warning.

You don't have the built-in profiler enabled so that you can get diagnostics like CPU and memory usage, which are useful for when IntelliJ becomes unresponsive or sluggish.

Don't worry about it; if you don't encounter a lot of startup pain, then it's not anything critical.  If you *do* require the profiler enabled, then [you can follow the instructions here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) to add the appropriate run time flags to your executable.

Answer (score -1):

does Mint use the oraclejdk?  or the openjdk?  intellij recommends the use of oraclejdk for Idea.  it fixed at least one problem i had with it under fedora (at the cost of some disk space).

Comment: I'm already using oracle jdk.I don't know how to solve this problem and what else try to solve.